# Split function's declaration and definition, or delete new operator in header?

Tags: c++, include, new-operator

I'm new in C++, and I have difficulty in my project.

Super.h

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>

float *list=new float[10];

class Super{
public:
    void function(){}
};
```

A.h

```
#pragma once
#include "Super.h"

class A{  
public:
    void function();
};
```

A.cpp

```
#include "A.h"
void A::function(){
    std::cout<<"Working A!"<<std::endl;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "A.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    A a;
    a.function();
    return 0;
}
```

This code is not compiled,(clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)) and I found if I delete

```
float *list=new float[10];
```

in Super.h, It compiled.

However, I need the array that can be accessed in class A. So I have tried many ways, and found it can be compiled if I leave float array, and  combine A.h and A.cpp, like

```
//Super.h    

float *list=new float[10];

class Super{

public:
    void function(){}
};

------------------------------------
// A.h

#pragma once
#include "Super.h"


class A{

public:    
    void function();
};

void A::function(){
    std::cout<<"Working A!"<<std::endl;
}
```

Do I have to combine A.cpp and A.h? or is my design bad? I use XCode 8.

Comment: That's a global variable. It's bad practice. Maybe you could tell us a bit more about what you want to do with `list` could it be a member, or static member of `A` for example?

Comment: Yes, having a global variable `float *list=new float[10];` is bad design. But the actual cause is because you declare a global variable in a header file.

Comment: No, the actual cause is that you declare a global variable in a header file, then include that header file in multiple translation units.

Comment: @JinoPark Even if I had time to look over all your code, I'd still need you to explain what you were doing with it. Can you explain what this is used for? Is it only used by `class A`? If not what else uses it?

Comment: @JonathanMee https://github.com/pjessesco/2017-Cpp/tree/master/In%20winter../Week5 I tried to make geometrical object using class. When I input x and y coordinates to draw, values in pixel array in Setting.h change, so it may draw.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't know I can't newline in comment...

Comment: @JinoPark It sounds to me as though `list` should be an object type and rather than `class A` you should just write it a constructor.

Comment: @JonathanMee Thanks for helping, but I can't understand exactly. You mean that should I make `list` as an object using class? and what does it mean 'just write it a constructor?'

Comment: Rather than having a global `list` variable, I'm suggesting that you should be passing around a `vector<float>` or if that container is too rudimentary for your needs then create your own class which can be passed around. To discuss how this would happen, let's start with this: 1) What would an `A` object do to your current `list`? 2) What should cause an `A` object to do this? 3) How would `list` be used after being updated by the `A` object?

Comment: @JonathanMee Thanks so much. I'll try it!

Comment: @JinoPark You seemed willing to give it a shot, so I've made my recommendations for what would need to change in your code in an answer. Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your actual code, "`line`" is declared in [Settings.h](https://github.com/pjessesco/2017-Cpp/blob/master/In%20winter../Week5/Setting.h) and used in it's `drawPixel` function.

The only other place that it's used is in [main.cpp](https://github.com/pjessesco/2017-Cpp/blob/master/In%20winter../Week5/main.cpp) I'm going to discuss these points in reverse order so our discussion can make more sense:

- Cleanup: `delete[] pixels` You should be using a `vector<float>` instead so you avoid all the problems associated with dynamic memory:

  1. What if `drawPixel` is called after cleanup?
  2. What if your code exits with an error?
  3. How will you ensure that your `main` function doesn't exit early and miss this?
- Usage: `glDrawPixels(width, height, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, pixels)` The final [`glDrawPixels`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glDrawPixels.xml) parameter is of type `void*` So, if you've correctly replaced `pixels` with a `vector<float>` you can make the implicit conversion by passing `data(pixels)`
- Initialization: `fill_n(pixels, width*height * 3, 1.0f)` Rather than in [Settings.h](https://github.com/pjessesco/2017-Cpp/blob/master/In%20winter../Week5/Setting.h), this is where `pixels` should be defined: `vector<float> pixels(width * height * 3, 1.0F)` you'll need to make these changes to your system to avoid the global variable:

  1. All instances of `void draw()` will need to be changed to `void draw(vector<float>& pixels)` and when any `draw` method is called `pixels` will be the argument
  2. `void drawPixel(const int& i, const int& j, const float& red, const float& green, const float& blue)` should be changed to `void drawPixel(vector<float>& pixels, const int i, const int j, const float red, const float green, const float blue)` and any call to the `drawPixel` function must take `pixel` as it's 1<sup>st</sup> argument
  3. `void drawLine(const int& i0, const int& j0, const int& i1, const int& j1, const float& red, const float& green, const float& blue)` should be changed to `void drawLine(vector<float>& pixels, const int i0, const int j0, const int i1, const int j1, const float red, const float green, const float blue)` and any call to the `drawLine` function must take `pixel` as it's 1<sup>st</sup> argument

Comment: Thanks for your kindness answer! I have some questions. Is there a difference between `std::vector<float> pixels(width*height*3,0.0f);` and `float *list=new float[10];`? I thought that variables defined outside { } were called global variables...

Comment: @JinoPark You're correct that variables declared within a namespace scope (not a function's scope) are globals. Don't declare those. In my last bullet point I suggest you define `pixels` within `main`'s scope. This is why you'll have to add it as a reference parameter to be passed from `main` into any function that will need it (even if it's passed multiple times, like in `drawPixel` or `drawLine`'s case.) As far as why you'd want to use a `vector` instead of a dynamically allocated array, that's discussed in the first bullet, but basically so the standard will manage your memory for you.

Comment: It works when I make pixel vector in my main function. However it still does not compile when I split function's definition and declaration into, for example, Line.h and Line.cpp..  I found that _duplicate symbol error_ is caused when global variable is included more than twice in header. I changed `const int width=640` into `#define Width 640` to remove global variables, but It still does not working... Also I put `#pragma once`, I think headers are not duplicated..

Comment: @JinoPark I'm sorry but it's too hard for me to understand: "It still does not compile when I split function's definition and declaration into, for example, Line.h and Line.cpp." It should be fine to put the declaration in Line.h and the definition in Line.cpp. But you've probably got a syntax error on one of those. If you can create another Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example, ask the question using that example, and link the question here, I'd be happy to come try to answer.

Comment: Thanks, Jonathan, very much for helping me. :) I'll try it